# default NULL is not set

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am having a problem with contenteditable. I am trying to make a ajax post methot using contenteditable. I have two contenteditable div.

If it does not write anything, it must be `NULL` from the database table but it shows empty post not setting *`NULL`*.

**AJAX**

```
$("body").on("click", ".post", function() {
   var text1 = $("#text1").html();
   var text2 = $("#text2").html();
   
   var data = 'text1=' + encodeURIComponent(text1) + '&text2=' + encodeURIComponent(text2);
   
      $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         url: '/requests/post.php',
         data: data,
         cache: false,
         beforeSend: function() {
            // Do something
         },
         success: function(html) {
            console.log("post sended");
         }
      });
   
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="abc" id="text1" contenteditable="true" placeholder="Write something1"></div>
<div class="text2" id="text2" contenteditable="true" placeholder="Write something2"></div>
```

**post.php**

```
<?php 
include "../inc/inc.php";
if(isset($_POST['text1'])){
    $text1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['text1']);
    $text2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['text2']);
    $data = $POST->POST($uid,$text1, $text2); 
}
?>
```

and POST function

```
public function POST($uid,$text1, $text2) {
    
    
    $time=time(); // Current post time
    $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; // user ip
    $query = mysqli_query($this->db,"SELECT post_id,text1,text2 FROM `posts` WHERE uid_fk='$uid' order by post_id desc limit 1") or die(mysqli_error($this->db));
    $result = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC); 
    // Add the insert POST
     $query = mysqli_query($this->db,"INSERT INTO `posts` (text1,text2, uid_fk,time) VALUES ('$text1','$text2','$uid','$time')") or die(mysqli_error($this->db));
     
}
```

All code is working fine.But problem is text2. If doesn't write any text it is showing empty result in database. I want to set id default *`NULL`*

[image]

Wrong way,

[image]

It should looks like this

[image]

What i am missing here? Anyone can help me in this regard ?

Comment: _All code is working fine_ ?? Did you see this: `VALUES (N'$text1',` ??

Comment: Also if you insert an empty text is becomes an empty string AND not real  `NULL` in the database. This will be text in the db `('','foobar')` this will be a NULL in db `(NULL,'foobar')`, so do for `$test2` a precheck like `$test2 = $test2?"'$test2'":'null';` and paste that into the query, `('$text1',$test2)`, here no single quotes (added in the prerecheck).

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions  `$test2 = $test2?"'$test2'":'null';` this 'null'; is just a text i want to get default `NULL`

Comment: Yep it is text, but TEXT for the query, that will become a real null in the DB because of the missing single quotes in the query. `('null') != (NULL)` first will be a text in the database with the content `null`, second will become a real null, did you get it now?

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions It is not getting default NULL from database, it is getting just a text. I think the problem is contenteditable because it i use normal textarea or input text then i am getting default null if text2 is empty.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're passing an `empty value` instead of `null` itself

Just check if the string is `empty` and put null if it's empty

```
if(isset($_POST['text1'])){
    $text1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['text1']);
    $text2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['text2']);
    $text1 = !empty($text1) ? $text1 : null;
    $text2 = !empty($text2) ? $text2 : null;
    $data = $POST->POST($uid,$text1, $text2); 
}
```

And also you're `insert` statement is adding `'` around the string which will make `null` as string `'null'` :

So to process accordingly use pdo:

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname","$dbusername","$dbpassword");
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO `posts` (text1,text2, uid_fk,time) VALUES (:text1,:text2,:uid,:time)");

$statement->execute(array(':text1'=>$text1,
                          ':text2', $text2,
                          ':uid', $uid,
                          ':time', $time
                    ));
```

**Edit:**

For some reasons if you can't or don't want to use PDO. You'd end up hacking in the sql. Something like:

```
$text2 = !empty($text2) ? "'".$text2."'":null;
$text1 = !empty($text1) ? "'".$text1."'":null;
$query = mysqli_query($this->db,"INSERT INTO `posts` (text1,text2, uid_fk,time) VALUES ($text1,$text2,'$uid','$time')");
```

Comment: This will still write a empty string into the table.

Comment: Look at the end of my updated answer. But first look what `POST($uid,$text1, $text2)` does with the parameter ;-)

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions looked at it and yes that shows my ans will insert db `null` not empty string

Comment: lol @JustOnUnderMillions no way I'm using pdo so probably you should learn how it works. Cheers

Comment: ?!?!? I know how PDO works (who says i dont), but an good answer will take what the OP uses and he uses MYSQLI, and you force him a solution to change to PDO, ok,  but im out know for real.

Comment: @NishanthMatha Thanks for your answer. But JustOnUnderMillions is right because your answer gives me normal text **null** . It sould be work if `$text2` is empty then set default `NULL` from database table for `$text2`

Answer (score 0):

Add a precheck to the logic, because you have to give `NULL` or not useing the field in the insert to get an real `NULL` in the table.

```
// Add the insert POST
 $text2 = $text2?"'$text2'":'NULL';
 $query = mysqli_query($this->db,"INSERT INTO `posts` (text1,text2, uid_fk,time) VALUES ('$text1',$text2,'$uid','$time')") or die(mysqli_error($this->db));
```

**INSERT TEXT vs NON-TEXT**

Insert a real `NULL`

`INSERT INTO posts (text1) VALUES (null)`

Insert a text with content `NULL`

`INSERT INTO posts (text1) VALUES ('NULL')`

Insert table default:

`INSERT INTO posts (text1) VALUES (default)`

Insert a text with content `default`

`INSERT INTO posts (text1) VALUES ('default')`

**To understand it more here an example sql:**

`INSERT INTO test (testfield) VALUES (null), ('null'), (default), ('') ;`

Make a table `test` with one field `VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL` and execute the SQL and look what you get. You will get 2 entries with real null, one with empty string and one with an string `null`.